# C program to print an irregular star pattern

Tags: c, ascii-art

I am trying to write a program that will make a pattern of stars. The last line is really tripping me up. I have to make the code only using the `printf("*");` `printf(" ");` `printf("\n");` statements once. I want to accomplish this with a for loops and if statements.

It is supposed to look like this:

```
             * - 5 spaces before *
           * * - 4 spaces before *  
         * * * - 3 spaces before * 
   * * * * * * - 0 spaces before *
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    i=1;
    j=1;
    for(i=4;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
        {
            if(j>=i || ((i+j)==5) && !(j==2) && !(j==3))
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and

```
main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=4;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(k=4;k>=i;k--) 
        {
            if((k>=i) ||((k>=i) && ((i+k)==5)))
            {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I think my first approach is way off. But I think I am on to something in the second link. I'm trying to print the "*" and extra 2 times on the fourth line. the second link the compiler appears to be ignoring the || operator.  How should I change my if statement to make this pattern work?

Comment: should the program be static or would you like to change the number of lines that be printed? And why it goes down from 5,4,3 and then 0?

Comment: Post the code inline to keep SO independent of other web sites.

Comment: The code is meant to be static. I wanted the first 3 lines to follow a pattern and the fourth line to be an exception to the pattern. I thought I could accomplish this with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting anything, take a look at the algorithm you're going to need to implement. Let's say we want to make a triangle with size 4.
There's will be 3 spaces before the first *. Then on the next line it will be 2 spaces, and so on. decrements the number of spaces each line, and with that increment the number of *s each line.

Our first loop, the outer loop, will be the loop that needs to go to the next line.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
printf("\n");
```

No we need to make it so it prints the correct number of spaces each line. Knowing that the first line has a size - 1 # of spaces, we get this

```
spaces = size - 1;
for(x = 0; x < spaces; x++)
printf(" ");
```

Now we place that in the scope of outer loop, since we want it to do that for every line.
We also need to change the value of spaces after each line, since it decrements every line.

```
int x, i;
spaces = size - 1;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
 for(x = 0; x < spaces; x++)
  printf(" ");
 spaces--;
 printf("\n");
}
```

Finally we need it to print the *s. As you notices, the number of *s starts at 1 and increments every line. So we make another for loop

```
int stars = 1;
for(a = 0; a < stars; a++)
  printf("*");
```

Once that's finished, we need to put that in the scope of our outer loop, AFTER the spaces.

```
int x, i, a;
spaces = size - 1;
stars = 1;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
 for(x = 0; x < spaces; x++)
  printf(" ");
 for(a = 0; a < stars; a++)
  printf("*");
 spaces--;
 stars++;
 printf("\n");
}
```

And there you have it. I typed all this in the forum box so there might be some syntax typos, but this should be more than enough. That's the basic start drawing method. Now all you have to do is the irregular part.
I'll let you handle that though, it's as simple as initializing the spaces variable to compensate for the last row being long. Once you compensate for the spaces, have your last line of code print out all the stars

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do too much at a time in a function (`main()`), that's why you're failing the logic. Split the problem into smaller, *independent* pieces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printNSpaces(int count);
void printNStars(int count);

int main(void) {
    int n;

    for (n = 1; n <= 6; ++n) {
        printNSpaces(6 - n);
        printNStars(n);
        (void) printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void printNSpaces(int count) {
    while (count--) {
        (void) printf(" ");
    }
}

void printNStars(int count) {
    while (count--) {
        (void) printf("*");
    }
}
```

The exception(s) should be easy to add to this.

`printNSpaces()` and `printNStars()` are very similar and could be merged into a single, generic function `void printN(char c, int count)`, but then you wouldn't be using the required `printf(" ")` and `printf("*")` statements.